# Enter key to search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am trying to figure out why my function to run the submit(searchBtn) is not working correctly. If you have any idea on what is going wrong, I would appreciate the help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Click searchbtn and run our search

  $('#searchBtn').click(function() {
    // Get value of our searchbar that user inputs
    var searchInput = $('#searchInput').val();
    //reset our textbox when search is called
    $('#searchInput').val('');
    //set our search url with the API and searchInput
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchInput + "&format=json&callback=?";

      $.ajax({
        data: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

           $('#output').html('');
           for (let i = 0; i < data[1].length; i += 1) {
            $('#output').append("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" + data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][0] + "</p></li>");
           }

        },
        error: function(errorMessage) {
          alert("There was a problem retrieving your results.");
        }
    })
```

This is the function to run the click function when the enter key is released. It appears directly after the code example above.

```
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
          $('#searchBtn').click();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: remove the click and keyup events, and bind to the submit event of the form.

Comment: `var searchBtn = '#searchBtn'; ` ??

Comment: ´is not working correctly´ not working how? Have you checked your console for errors? What's the expected result and what is happening instead?

Comment: what is exactly your error?  is the submit callback fired? did you get the response?

Comment: any errors in console?  you sure the function not running? or the something else is wrong?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. When the enter key is pressed, I want to run the click function assigned to the searchBtn Id above that runs the ajax call. @empiric

Comment: Does it work on a normal click?

Comment: yes it works when I click the submit/search btn

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, it removes the programmatic click and just runs the function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   //Click searchbtn and run our search

   function search() {
    // Get value of our searchbar that user inputs
    var searchInput = $('#searchInput').val();
    //reset our textbox when search is called
    $('#searchInput').val('');
    //set our search url with the API and searchInput
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchInput + "&format=json&callback=?";

      $.ajax({
        data: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

           $('#output').html('');
           for (let i = 0; i < data[1].length; i += 1) {
            $('#output').append("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" + data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][0] + "</p></li>");
           }

        },
        error: function(errorMessage) {
          alert("There was a problem retrieving your results.");
        }
    }

$('#searchBtn').click(search);
$('#searchInput').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      search();
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: This looks a lot better but it still does not run when the enter key is pressed. I can still access the ajax call when the submit button is pressed @SethWhite

Comment: Interesting... do you have any other events that are collecting keystrokes? And are those events calling anything like preventDefault()? Drop a console log in your keyup function callback and see if it's even being called. If it isn't, something is intercepting your keyup event.

Comment: That's what is so weird. Nothing should be preventing it from being called, but I consoled it out and nothing was printed. I even wrote out your code and commented out mine and nothing changed. It's a codepen so if you would like to check it out, it is at http://codepen.io/JonLangel/pen/JbJddX

Comment: Sorry, got caught up, looks like you fixed it on your codepen. I'm guessing it's because it was in a form that you had to do the event.preventDefault. Good to know :) You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I will do so. Yes it was! I had to make sure that there was the event.preventDefault for both the 'enter' key and the submit button. I also had a `required` attribute on my `<input>` that shouldn't be there!

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the help of @SethWhite and some people from /r/learnprogramming with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Click searchbtn and run our search

   function search() {
    // Get value of our searchbar that user inputs
    var searchInput = $('#searchInput').val();

    //reset our textbox when search is called
    $('#searchInput').val('');
    //set our search url with the API and searchInput
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchInput + "&format=json&callback=?";

      $.ajax({
        data: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

           $('#output').html('').addClass('animated slideInUp');

           for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
            $('#output').append("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" + data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");
           }

        },
        error: function(errorMessage) {
          alert("There was a problem retrieving your results.");
        }
    })
    $('#output').removeClass();
   }
  $('#searchBtn').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      search();
    });
  $('#searchInput').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      search();
    }
  });
});
```

Using event.preventDefault(); takes care of this, since each time the ajax is called, we are resetting the `#seachInput` with `''` causing the input form to alert you of an empty form.